# Apache2, mod_rewrite - use variable from prev condition in next condition

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

I would like to check if file exist in subdirectory.
And I mean subdirectory that "is taken" from "subdomain".

Eg. url: "test.domain.com/file.txt" file location is "/test/file.txt"

I have wildacrd and i can't hardcode "test" directory. How can i do it?

I tried add `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1/$1`  but this dosen't work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain.com
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%1/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain.com
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /%1/image.php?test=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/$1 -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ %1/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)/?$ %1/image.php?test=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

***Fixes in OP's attempts:*** You need not to use condition `RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$` in 2nd Rules sets, even first one may not need it but for safer side you can have it. Then your sequence of accessing path from %{DOCUMENT_ROOT} was not correct which was corrected here.

Comment: @iknownothing, sorry but you need to provide more information on which sample url is not working? What error are you getting?

Comment: My mistake i did not change line "RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ %1/$1 [L]" not its working.  Can you explain a bit what was problem with my rules ?  Thanks a lot

Comment: @iknownothing, oh ok, thanks for letting know. Cheers and happy learning.